# Detecting Chrome App Windows Opening

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to detect when Chrome App windows open.

It is possible to get the currently open app windows using `chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true, windowTypes: [ "app" ]}, callback)`, but the `chrome.windows.onCreated` event does not fire for app windows.

The documentation states that a window type filter can somehow be specified for the event, but does not specify how to use it. `chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener([ "app" ], callback)` fails with "Uncaught Error: Can't add listener".

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated

Comment: chrome extensions or chrome app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are specified as an object after the callback. App windows opening can be observed using `chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(callback, { windowTypes: [ "app" ] })`

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered

Comment: It sure would be nice if the Chrome API docs specified that where they document the various event types, as how to use the filters is otherwise completely opaque.